# Can members of Hatzolah learn how to deliver a baby?

Tags: women, medicine, pregnancy-birth, employment, men-male

This seems like a very simple thing. Is there anything wrong with male members of Hatzolah (a frum Jewish emergency medical organization) learning how to deliver a baby? I recently heard that Rabbonim were asked this question and didn't want to answer. It seems like a very simple thing to me that they *should* know how. Are there any teshuvas on this or Rabbonim that have taken an official stance.

See here (related): [May a man become a gynecologist?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/may-a-man-become-a-gynecologist)

Comment: Seems to me the opposite: Could someone possibly become a member of hatzalaha *without* learning how to deliver a baby???? I read over an EMT manual and there was a complete chapter on delivering a baby in there, I can't imaging you could become an EMT without learning that.

Comment: @Ariel That just leads to the question of if they can become EMTs.

Comment: I wanted to answer this question but would have ended up duplicating what I wrote [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95061/11501) since my research led me to exactly the same sources!

Comment: If he could ever be the only one who can deliver the baby, wouldn’t that be safek pikuach nefesh?