# Being treated by a female doctor

Tags: halacha, health-safety-shmira, negia

Regarding the *Issur* of *שומר נגיעה* that prohibits the touching of a woman , would it be permitted for a **young man** to be treated by a **female** doctor  in an office? Sources are appreciated .

Comment: See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3760

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38250/5083

Comment: I assume this is not a pekuach nefesh situation when of course it would be permitted, but simply a case of a minor injury or ailment that is not life threatening.

Comment: When I had an issue with a private part of my body earlier in the year and had to see a GP in the surgery I did particularly request a male doctor due to the nature of why I was going to see them.

Comment: @Matt, that question appears to be particularly about the doctor seeing body parts, while this question appears to be particularly about touching.

Comment: @IsaacMoses so... That makes it not related?

Comment: @Matt, sorry; I was responding to the votes to close as duplicate and glossed over the fact that your comment just said "Related." +1 for the link.

Comment: Related problem, maybe. Isn't there a problem of *yichud* when the exam room door is closed?