# Can one get their hair cut by someone of the other gender?

Tags: tznius-modesty, haircuts

Can one get their head hair cut by someone of the opposite gender? Is the unavoidable proximity and contact problematic?

Assume no issue of seclusion applies. I'm asking about the issue of proximity and contact only.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38250/759 Hair amputation is a non-life-threatening medical procedure

Comment: I think contact during a hair cut is sufficiently different to the issues of nakedness during medical procedures raised in that question?

Comment: I guess I figured that question was intended to cover all aspects of modesty (eg. touching) not just seeing. Certainly many aspects are applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

According to [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2010/06/06/haircut-from-a-woman/) and their sources below, "it is not permitted for a man to receive  a haircut from a woman. Because the need for a haircut is not considered a state of “illness”, and because the close contact with a woman is liable to cause the man hirhurim, a long list of authorities has written that it is prohibited."

Sources: Yalkut Yosef (EvenHa’Ezer 21:5); Rivevos Efraim (5:507); Hilel Omer (Even He’Ezer 38, p. 400); Yitzchak Yeranen (vol. II, Even Ha’Ezer 1); Olam Yitzchak (2:237); Netzach Yosef (1:66); Mitzvos Ha-Nashim (35:12, and sources no. 14).

Comment: However, the Rama (EH 21:5) notes the custom is to be lenient in these matters in public settings, and even to allow female servants to wash a man's body.

Comment: I haven't checked all your sources yet, but Rivevot Efraim doesn't provide any basis for his prohibiting this; he just says it's obvious, and then notes some source that indicate Peritzut is really bad.

Comment: Even if the woman is a close relative, such as your mother or sister?

Comment: Any more lenient sources?

Comment: @Ezra See the link to dinonline who pasken  it is permitted to receive a haircut from one’s wife (when she is ‘permitted’), and from one’s mother or daughters.

Comment: @NJM - Great - my hair is cut by my mother! Best barber in the world!! :)

Comment: @DoubleAA Although the Rema (21:5) is lenient concerning acts that are not intimate, he mentions that “checking hair” is considered “intimate.” Thus, the Rabbonim at dinonline assert the same would be true of a haircut.

Comment: @El Shteiger Sorry, in the process of trying to find a kulah for you, I stumbled upon more poskim who are machmir: Lev Chaim 2:4, Be’er Moshe 4:126, Rivevos Ephraim 5:507, 6:page 535, 8:596:4, Halichos Bas Yisroel page 95, V’ein Lumo Michshal 1:page 116.

Comment: @NJM are you joking? Washing ones body is not intimate but giving a haircut is? Checking for lice isn't a haircut anyway. That's aside from the fact that the midas chasidus about checking for lice is a completely separate issue from this and it's about being close with ones wife in public.

Comment: @DoubleAA You can take a look at the link to their teshuva yourself, I'm not kidding. Although I agree with you that it would make more sense to say washing ones body is more intimate than a haircut, in their defense the nosei keilim agree if one would have difficulty with hirhurim then it's all assur. It wouldn't surprise me if most men would have difficulty not stumbling in thought by being walked around in a very close proximity for ~20 minutes...