# Non-Jews touching Jews For Medical Care in an Emergency

Tags: halacha, gentiles, health-safety-shmira, negia

I come from a family of female nurses (Christian.) Would it be allowed for them to give aid or help to the Orthodox community in an emergency since hand shaking is not allowed - we would not want to be inappropriate in any way in our community. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, in case of emergency almost all Jewish legal requirements are suspended. Second of all, while many Orthodox Jews do indeed refrain from any touching Jews of the opposite sex, some do not, as according to many opinions contact such as a handshake is permitted.

Comment: E. Romaine, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here, and for the spirit of sensitivity that drives it.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38250/759

Comment: Since this is a duplicate of a question with an answer of *yes*, the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction on Jews and non-Jews touching. There is a restriction  on touching between the sexes, regardless of faith, where the touching might lead to inappropriate behavior.  Different religious communities are strict to different degrees regarding this restriction, with some avoiding particularly affectionate touching, such as hugging or kissing, and others avoiding e.g. even formal handshakes.  In non-emergency situations, it is perhaps best to find out from the patient and/or his family what his comfort level is.  It is unlikely though that any community restricts non-sexual physical contact in the course of life-saving medical procedures.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate of another. You might want to move your answer over (but note that there is already a sourced answer there).